# How to start an Angular app from another web app with some parameters?

Tags: angular, web

Our team is developing new web app based on angular framework. Our app needs to be started from another browser web app (jquery-based) with some parameters.

Let's say, a user in a jquery app clicks a link "open another app" and this link leads to my app which has to be opened on a particular module and containing info about user that triggered my app from jquery app.

How do I pass values (startup module name, username and maybe some extra info) from jquery app to my angular app?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You could pass these values through the query string for starters.

Comment: You could just simply define a route for every component which must be invoked from outside and with the parameters inside the route itself, so that a basic `a` would be enough to take you to the right page.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for your response! Query string is my fallback way to implement this, because I don't wont to show sensitive info like username in the query string.

Comment: @bracco23 Thanks for the response. It doesn't seem very extensible solution to implement it through links, since info to be passed is not limited to component name, but also may contain username and some other data which may grow up easily in future.

Comment: If you add an example of the data you have to pass and the reason, it would be easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: @user3680171 just remember *nothing* you do on the client side is secure. No matter where you set these values, be it in the query string, session or local storage, you can access these values.